# Cinnamon Control Center pkg and zip repo have no ability to ./configure

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I've spent significant time googling, tinkering, and stressing about this.  I've never used ./configure; make; make install, but this git repo has exactly what I want for the Cinnamon theme in Ubuntu 12.04 and can only be installed via ./configure; make; make install.

I've downloaded this zip repo, but can't even find src anywhere in it.  I even spent a long time trying ./console in multiple directories, only to later learn it should be in /usr/src or something.  I'm still learning linux..

https://github.com/linuxmint/cinnamon-control-center

I've even gone so far as to find a completely different zip of the same, supposed software on archlinux. It's a pkg.tar.xz and after I extracted it, it still didn't let me ./configure it.  It was also missing several files and didn't even look like the same as the one from github.  Here's the pkg:

https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/cinnamon-control-center/

Am I losing my mind?  Shedding some light on this would really help me out.  I feel like it's all about time to ask for help.  The troubleshooting was a good learning experience.  I got to practice quite a few things like pwd, ls, cd, etc. to troubleshoot which was good.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming. Might be better suited on Super User (but please check the [faq](http://superuser.com/help) there first).

Comment: Not voting down, because it's a valid, pertinent question .. However my vote is move to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or [ubuntu.se], just check the [help/on-topic] of each site to see what's on-topic and what's not. And remembering that multi-posts are not encouraged.

Comment: That's true, it's not a programming question.  I think you have a good point that most people here are ready to answer coding questions and this might not even be the right community for my answer.

Comment: Can we move it to the right forum?  I'm banned for stackoverflow for bad questions and am trying to clean up.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Out of respect for everyone's time, actual questions regarding coding, and yadda yadda, I will say the following Ask Ubuntu thread will have the answer to this at some point.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/347634/cinnamon-control-center-both-archlinux-pkg-and-github-zip-repo-have-no-ability-t

However, I feel it's important to say that anyone embracing open source software like Ubuntu should get some extra love just because that's what it's all about.